# Problem with Scapy ARP request in netscanner

Tags: python, scapy

I was creating a netscanner using scapy, but i got an error...

When i put a normal ip address, the arp request arrive and return with no problem, but when i try to send it to all the ip in the network with ip/24 this error pop up!

Code:

```py
import scapy.all as scapy
import sys

if len(sys.argv)==2:
    def scan(ip):
        arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst = ip)
        arp_request.show()
        broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
        broadcast.show()
        arp_request_broadcast = broadcast/arp_request
        arp_request_broadcast.show()

    scan(sys.argv[1])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: what do you mean by "when i try to send it to all the ip in the network with ip/24" ?... What is your input to this code, and why?

Comment: If you want to send the arp request to all the client on the network, instead of typing any ip by hand, you type an ip (normaly end with .1) and after you put /24. I'm following a course online and to the guy who is making the course it work fine but not to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved it!
The arp_request.show() and arp_request_broadcast.show() created the error.
Simply remove them and it will work fine!